# Confused by REST API classes

Tags: java, rest, jersey, dropwizard

I am attempting to learn how to build a REST API with dropwizard using the 'getting started' tutorial they have on their site:

https://www.dropwizard.io/en/stable/getting-started.html

I am very confused as to the purposes of all of the classes that must be created in order for program to work. The tutorial somewhat explains the classes, but I found the explanations to be extremely vague and cryptic. Can someone explain to me what the purpose of each class is in layman's terms?

1. Configuration Class
2. Application Class
3. Representation Class
4. Resource Class

Answer (score 0):

Note that the formatting is not suitable for comment:

I've made a simple use case diagram. Take a look if it helps you.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can be a little daunting for someone just starting to get familiar with Dropwizard, but the documentation tries its best to explain what these classes do. I'll do my best to simplify each of these classes so it's easier to understand them, and also give you some examples of how you can structure your code:

**1. Configuration class**

Assuming we are building a somewhat complex application, possibly the backend of a service, we need configuration (possibly a config.yml). Once we wrote any configuration fields we needed, a configuration class will be useful because it will deserialize the information in the config file and make it available in an ApplicationConfiguration class for our dropwizard application to use.

```
Each Dropwizard application has its own subclass of the Configuration class which specifies environment-specific parameters.
```

You pretty much need one of these classes to create your Dropwizard application, and it is good practice as well.

**2. Application class**

An application class is what I like to think as the bootloader of, well, your application! It uses that configuration class you just wrote, and it starts running your Dropwizard Application. It's also got some handy methods (like initialize and run), which you can use to initialize anything you need to get your application functional (maybe you want to setup dependency injection or add some bundles, anything you can think you'll need for your application to run)

**3. Representation class**

This is on the lowest level: the bare model of what you are trying to get. Maybe we are making a Dropwizard application to access user data, so your representation class will be a User class. It's just a simple POJO(Plain Old Java Object) class, somewhat abstracted from all the Dropwizard stuff.

**4. Resource class**

You build your REST service using resource classes. Depending on what you need, you can establish several endpoints to provide GET, POST, PUT, etc, requests for your UI codebase/or someone else to access. It is a way for others to access your representation classes and what you are interested in. It exposes the REST service of your application pretty much.

Hopefully that clears up some of the confusion.